# X11VNC dont work properly with gdm3

Tags: debian, vnc

Im using X11VNC service (installed from packages) and debian 9 with gdm3.

I created systemd file:

```
root@PCA55:/home/suser# cat /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
[Unit]
Description=VNC
Requires=display-manager.service
After=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -xkb -env FD_XDM=1 -auth guess -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -rfbauth /etc/vnc_passwd -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But X11VNC still wont work fine. When i connect - i have error:
`unable connect to socket: Connection refused`

I understand that there are some news in GDM3 and VNC, but cant find workable issue.
P.S I saw that [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/848078/x11vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04-gnome-with-systemd). But it helpless.

Could you help to find info how works?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `-auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`.
If this can not work, type `ps aux | grep Xorg` could find authority file of Xorg, just like follow:

```
user   3074  3072  0 17:01 tty2     00:00:02 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```